# How to stop all previous animations in jQuery before executing new one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am just experimenting something with jQuery.

I have an image which fades into another image as `mouseOver()` occurs and fades back on `mouseOut()`

It works great, except if you are moving your mouse over the link again and again, say 5 times, the image fades in and out repeatedly, 5 times while you just sit there and wait for it to get over with this crazy behaviour.

To stop this behaviour, I tried to use a flag and start the animation ONLY if it isn't already animating, but, guess what? If, say, I have 4 such buttons, and on each button mouseover I am fadingIn a different image, that animation will be ignored since the flag is false.

So is there a way to stop all the previous animations before executing new ones?
I am talking about the normal `fadeIn()` and `slideDown()` functions in JQuery

---

*EDIT: Adding code from link.*

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseOver="mouseOverOut(false);" onMouseOut="mouseOverOut(true);">Tick</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function mouseOverOut(t)
{
    if(t)
    {
        $('.img1').fadeIn();
        $('.img2').fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.img1').fadeOut();
        $('.img2').fadeIn();
    } 
}
```

Comment: @patrick grrrrrrr you exposed my childish function naming habits!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `.stop()` with `fadeIn/Out` can cause the opacity to get stuck in a partial state.

One solution is to use `.fadeTo()` instead, which gives an absolute destination for the opacity.

```
function mouseOverOut(t) {
    if(t) {
        $('.img1').stop().fadeTo(400, 1);
        $('.img2').stop().fadeTo(400, 0);
    }
    else {
        $('.img1').stop().fadeTo(400, 0);
        $('.img2').stop().fadeTo(400, 1);
    } 
}
```

Here's a shorter way of writing it.

```
function mouseOverOut(t) {
    $('.img1').stop().fadeTo(400, t ? 1 : 0);
    $('.img2').stop().fadeTo(400, t ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Or this may work. Test it first, though.

```
function mouseOverOut(t) {
    $('.img1').stop().fadeTo(400, t);
    $('.img2').stop().fadeTo(400, !t);
}
```

*EDIT: This last one seems to work. The true/false is translated to 1/0. You could also use `.animate()` directly.*

```
function mouseOverOut(t) {
    $('.img1').stop().animate({opacity: t});
    $('.img2').stop().animate({opacity: !t});
}
```

Comment: Using the goToEnd-argument of stop() should be able to avoid this.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - Yes, that's an option, but the effect is more jarring in my opinion.

Comment: of course, it should look much better if the animation could end smooth like you suggest :)

Comment: 2 years after you gave that answer, still people (well..me) using it!
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Did you already  try [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) ?

***Description:** Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.*

Comment: No, I havent tried stop, is it an independent function? should I just call it like ``stop()`` ? will try this now and report back, thanks

Answer (score 1):

using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop)