# Jquery box animation for shrinking and expanding more than one box at a time

Tags: jquery, animation, html, hover, jquery-animate

I've got an idea I want to pull off, and I've half done it but now I'm a little stuck and need some help.

I have 3 images.. each around 200px wide... when you hover over an image the image in question becomes bigger and makes the other two smaller.

I've managed this .. here is my [demo](http://tomwheldon.com/test/)

My code is as follows: (You might see it a bit sloppy but I'm new to jquery.

```
<style type="text/css">

body,
html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#outerbox1,
#outerbox2,
#outerbox3 {
    background-color:#000;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#box1 {
    background-image:url(mqdefault1.jpg);
}
#box2 {
    background-image:url(mqdefault2.jpg);
}
#box3 {
    background-image:url(mqdefault3.jpg);
}
</style>


<div id="outerbox1">
<div id="box1">

</div>
</div>

<div id="outerbox2">
<div id="box2">

</div>
</div>

<div id="outerbox3">
<div id="box3">

</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#outerbox1").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "320px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "140px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "140px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "200px" });
});

$("#outerbox2").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "320px" });
    $("#outerbox1").animate({ width: "140px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "140px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox1").animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "200px" });
});

$("#outerbox3").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "320px" });
    $("#outerbox1").animate({ width: "140px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "140px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox1").animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "200px" });
});
</script>
```

So my problem is if I hover over box 1... then box 2. I have to wait for box 1 to shrink before box 2 starts to expand.

How would I go about making it so box 2 starts to expand while box 1 is shrinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the mouseleave/handlerOut firing on each of those boxes. If you wrap your boxes in one container and only handle the mouseleave on that, you should get the behavior you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/FQ5ae/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="outerbox1">
        <div id="box1">  

        </div>
    </div>
    ...and so on
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#container").hover(function() {
    //nothing for handlerIn
}, function() {
    $("#outerbox1").animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "200px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "200px" });
});

$("#outerbox1").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "320px" });
    $("#outerbox2").animate({ width: "140px" });
    $("#outerbox3").animate({ width: "140px" });
}, function() {  
    //nothing for handlerOut
});
...and so on
```

Comment: This is the one...

Thanks everyone for telling me about STOP... but the main thing I needed was them to move together... and this script did it.

I've added in stops as well and the code runs like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
$("#outerbox1").stop().hover(function(){...
$("#outerbox2").stop().hover(function(){...
$("#outerbox2").stop().hover(function(){...
```

Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096357/how-to-stop-all-previous-animations-in-jquery-before-executing-new-one) might help.

Cheers!!!